# testing ssl with silverlight and wcf

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, ssl, https

I want to do https testing in the development environment.

I followed a tutorial to make a certificate and when I tried to connect it crashed saying that it was an untrusted certificate.

As I see it my options are:
1) Buy an expensive certificate for testing only
2) Write code as a work around (horrible) just to test.

What I would like to do...
Make a free certificate and no have different code between development and production.

Is this possible or is this just a dream?

Answer (score 1):

Download [IIS Express and Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/securing-web-communications-certificates-ssl-and-https) and with in seconds you will be able to add SSL to the development server.